# How to disallow users from accessing the application database when offering VM Image on Azure Marketplace?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-machine, iaas, azure-security

I would like to publish an image of a generalized VM on the Azure Marketplace. The VM for which the image is to be created includes an ASP.NET MVC Application which connects to a local SQL Server.

I would like to disallow access to my application's database to the users who create VMs from the offered image, so that they would not be able to see the stored procedures inside the database.

I was considering to disable Windows Authentication to the SQL server and adding a superadmin user who could access the server. However, in this case I would need to place the username and password of the superadmin user inside my web.config file thus making it visible to all users.

Are there any other possible solutions for restricting access to an application's database or more specifically the stored procedures in the database, when offering the application on a VM image?

Answer (score 1):

that wouldnt help, you can always force your way into sql server (since you control the vm). so this makes little sense really.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encrypt your stored procedures as shown below, but there are some third-party tools that can decrypt it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourSP_WithEncryption WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    -- START: Proprietary Business Logic
    --
    --
    --
    --
    -- END: Proprietary Business Logic

    SELECT 'From ENCRYPTED Stored Procedure'
END
GO
```

Alternatively, there are some third-party tools like [SqlShield](http://www.sql-shield.com/index.php) that can provide hacker-proof encryption to your stored procedures. It can also encrypt views and triggers.